# What‘s the principle of positioning exactly by bluetooth 5.1

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

bluetooth 5.1 specifications announced a new direction finding feature that holds the potential to significantly enhance the performance of Bluetooth location services solutions. The new feature allows devices to determine the direction of a Bluetooth signal, thereby enabling the development of Bluetooth proximity solutions that can understand device direction as well as Bluetooth positioning systems that can achieve down to centimeter-level location accuracy.

I want to know how to it implement this function

Answer (score 3):

The main two changes that enable this new location accuracy is the addition of **Angle of Arrival (AoA)**  and **Angle of Departure (AoD)**. AoA relies on the device (Locator, e.g. phone) having multiple antennas (e.g. four). When a packet is received, there will be a very slight time shift relative to each antenna (i.e. the packet will arrive in a slightly different time). This methodology is then used to determine which side the signal came from. AoD on the other hand is when the location tag itself has multiple antennas, and the packet propagates from each of these antennas. When the signal is received at the locator, the device will use algorithms to detect the relative signal direction.

There are a few articles already that are covering this subject. I highly recommend the following:-

- [Bluetooth 5.1 Puts Bluetooth In Its Place](https://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/bluetooth-5.1-puts-bluetooth-in-its-place?utm_campaign=Blog%20update%20notifications&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=69437923&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--s74GR99AiVc5OcFt9OuGAmm0mgS1B4Tg5jf79AKP-Jp9iTxDxdGwyh4L8WI_NDd1AJRiFPvAUqc0bP5CJTFqG92tChX76CZ8lAnIGClyfR7w54MY&_hsmi=69437923)
- [Bluetooth 5.1 Comes to Boost Indoor Navigation](https://www.gsmarena.com/bluetooth_51_gains_direction_finding_for_better_indoor_navigation_tracker_tags-news-35281.php)
- [Enhancing Bluetooth Location Services with Direction Finding](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/paper-enhancing-bluetooth?utm_source=li&utm_medium=social&utm_term=social&utm_content=li-dirfndngpaper-org&utm_campaign=location-services)

Please note that there will be a significant amount of time (maybe a year or two based on previous examples) for this feature to make it in everyday applications and for chip manufacturers and stack vendors to offer this functionality in their offerings.

Finally, I recommend posting a similar question in the future to other StackExchange networks (e.g. [ElectricalEngineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)) as StackOverflow is mainly for programming related questions and you'd probably get more traction and better answers in other sites.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply，so this new location accuracy of Bluetooth 5.1 relay on hardware design.

Comment: No problem. Yes you're right, it definitely depends on hardware changes but I'm guessing there'll be stack/software additions as well that accompany this.

Comment: Yes，may be need software algorithm support

Comment: Nicely said Youssif. You point up a common 'tripping point' often seen in product and programming discussions: 
  Not every problem has a software solution.
Without the extra antennas, and the radio firmware to support them, it is impossible to identify the direction of a signal. (well... you could put your phone in a parabolic faraday cage, I suppose :)